# Cómo obtener el contenido de un blog por ID desde Firebase Cloud Functions y mostrar una página en Nuxt.js con el contenido del blog capturado

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-storage, blog

Necesito mostrar un blog con Nuxt.js, usando algo como **nuxt-content**, **frontmatter-markdown-loader** o algo parecido y obtener el blog desde un link como `https://example.com/api/blog/${uid}` que seria el endpoint de mi Rest-Api (Firebase Cloud Functions) a la cual quiero llamar con Axios para mostrar el contenido del blog en pantalla.
He visto que con nuxt-content se hace de esta forma para mostrar un blog:

```
async asyncData({ $content, redirect, params }) {
        try {
            const uidBlog = params.uid
            const article = await $content('articles', uidBlog).fetch()

            return { article }
        } catch (err) {
            redirect('/blog')
        }
}
```

Pero yo quiero que desde el asyncData se recupere un archivo de tipo markdown (.md) desde mi Rest-Api Express (alojado en Firebase Cloud Functions) usando Firebase Cloud Storage y lo muestre en el blog.

Alguien sabe como realizar esto?